# How to convert one vectors to corresponding one-hot vector?

Tags: tensorflow

There is a vector of shape `(batch_size,)`.

It needs to be converted to shape `(batch_size, 2)` based on the sign.

Basically `(1,-2, 1) -> ((1,0), (0,1), (1,0),)`

What's a good way to do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot).